# How to install libbow in this time

Tags: apt, tools

In this time, I know that libbow(Bow: A toolkit for statistical language modeling, text retrieval) not updated anymore.
So, It's made an effect to latest Ubuntu cannot use it. (cannot compile libbow)

I try to use old version of Ubuntu8.04(hardy), but It's not working for libbow either because I cannot compile a C code in this version and I cannot use `sudo apt-get update` also in this version because of source.list, I think.

Is there has a way to install it, or Is there has any alternative toolkit which similar to libbow.

Thank for Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this web page.

[libbow_20020213-10_i386.deb](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/libbow_20020213-10_i386.deb.521278-0.html)

It's a deb package which we can instantly install libbow without compile manually needed, but It has x86 compatible versions and MIPS version also.

Moreover, I found [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org) toolkit, an alternative tool that quite similar to libbow.